# Does Azure have an out-of-box way of distributed locking with a key?

Tags: c#, azure, locking, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I want to be able to write code like

```
using (await LockAsync(x.Id))
{
    // here goes code that is unsafe with respect to x.Id
    // because it can be executed in multiple threads on
    // the same instance or on multiple instances (e.g.
    // multiple Azure Functions
}
```

I know there are out-of-box ways to lock an entire execution context without using a key (e.g. `[ActivityTrigger]` in Functions) and I know I could roll my own keyed lock using blob leases, but is there an out-of-box way for keyed lock?

Comment: As far as I know is there no way to have built in locks across multiple Azure Function Apps.

Comment: CloudBlobContainerDistributedLockManager in the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host namespace might be a good option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Redis distributed lock.

The package [RedLock.net](https://github.com/samcook/RedLock.net) provides exactly what you need:

```
var resource = "the-thing-we-are-locking-on";
var expiry = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);


using (var redLock = await redlockFactory.CreateLockAsync(resource, expiry)) // there are also non async Create() methods
{
   // make sure we got the lock
   if (redLock.IsAcquired)
   {
    // do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: after reading this https://martin.kleppmann.com/2016/02/08/how-to-do-distributed-locking.html, your view about Redis Distributed Lock will be not the same.

if you want a true distributed lock, Redis is not the answer.

Comment: @JengdiB thanks for sharing the link. Which approach would you suggest to use as a true distributed lock?

Comment: @R.Titvov I'm new to this concept too. But, I would go with Apache Zookeeper for my work. It's a persistent-connection style of distributed lock. If you lose a connection to the Zookeeper, you lose your lock and others can acquire it.

Comment: @JengdiB what will happen if one of instances loose connection to Zookeeper during an operation in a lock and another instance will acquire the lock and then first instance will restore the connection? Based on your previous comment looks like there will be two operations in a lock. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does in Azure Storage with the Lease a Blob feature. Azure Functions actually use this feature to co-ordinate between the multiple instances of your function.

If I want to create acquire a lock on `x.Id` I would use Azure Storage to get a 60s Storage Lease on a 0 bytes blob at path `/my-app-locks/{x.Id}`. If I get the lease I know I have the lock, and if not, then someone else does and I could then poll for it until they release it. You may also renew the 60s lease before it expires to extend the time.

This blog has some code and details, as well as other ways of implementing it - https://medium.com/@fbeltrao/distributed-locking-in-azure-functions-bc4517c0306c

Answer (score 1):

Though not "out of the box", I have found 2 Nuget packages which can use Azure Blob storage leases (amongst other techniques) of doing distributed locks.  YMMV:

[DistributedLock](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DistributedLock) (https://github.com/madelson/DistributedLock)

[DistributedLocks](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DistributedLocks/) (https://github.com/davidrevoledo/DistributedLocks)